# Creating a Cell Grid in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here is my GUI code, I am trying to create a cell grid however I am struggling to do so. Can somebody help?

```
JButton Game = null;
JButton Quit = null;
Container ctr = null;

public GUI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
    ctr = frame.getContentPane();
    ctr.setLayout(fl);
```

Creating a Frame with a container

```
    Game = new JButton("Start Game");
    Game.setToolTipText("Press button to start Game Of Life");
    ctr.add(Game);
    Game.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Game.addActionListener(this);
    //Creating a button to start the game 

    Quit = new JButton("Exit");
    Quit.setToolTipText("Click to exit program");
    ctr.add(Quit);
    Quit.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Quit.addActionListener(new CloseListener());
    //Creating a button to quit the game when clicked

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Game.setBounds(150,420,100,40);
    Quit.setBounds(250,420,100,40);
    //button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    These are the frame settings which are not final yet.
}
```

Comment: You can look at this: [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Take a look at my article, [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504), to see one way to create a Swing grid.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JTable like Tom suggests, or use GridLayout:

```
ctr.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0)); // 3 buttons across, X buttons down
```

Each cell is equal width/height, but is much more simple to use than JTable.

Comment: I've tried doing that, however nothing comes up on the interface.